# Concatenation of multiple HEX values in C

Tags: c, assembly, hex, concatenation

I have an array in memory that holds certain hex values that describe assembly instructions. For example:

```
708877665544332211 = jump 0x1122334455667788
```

`70` indicates a jump in assembly and the following hex numbers are what I need to concatenate. I've already tried doing,

```
address |= memory[1];
address |= memory[2]<<8;
address |= memory[3]<<16;
address |= memory[4]<<24;
address |= memory[5]<<32;
address |= memory[6]<<40;
address |= memory[7]<<48;
address |= memory[8]<<56;
```

The string that was outputted was:

> 0x100: 708877665544332211   |   jump 1432778700

Where am I going wrong in the concatenation?

EDIT: Following Benjamin's suggestion, I changed it to:

With print statement `printf("APPEND: %016llx", address)` to debug, I found that the `uint64_t` was being changed as:

```
APPEND: 0000000000002211
APPEND: 0000000000332211
APPEND: 0000000044332211
APPEND: 0000000044332255
APPEND: 0000000044336655
APPEND: 0000000044776655
```

If the address is a 64bit integer, why does it appear to be behaving as a 32bit integer?

Comment: I'd like to make an observation as to why your code doesn't work as you expected in the first case: Regarding `address |= memory[5]<<32;`, `address |= memory[6]<<40;`, `address |= memory[7]<<48;`, and `address |= memory[8]<<56;` there is the problem of integer promotion. `address |= memory[5]<<32;` for example will promote memory[5] to an int (on your platform a 32-bit value). If you attempt to shift that left 32 bits that exceeds the width of the 32-bit type.This will cause undefined behavior and is the reason you get unusual results place into `address`

Comment: You can cast using something like `address |= ((unsigned long long)memory[5])<<32` . This casts memory[5] to a 64-bit type and then the shift is performed on that. It is assumed you define `address` as an `unsigned long long`

Comment: I'm a bit surprised though that the compiler wouldn't have warned you about this issue at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decimal number 1432778700 in hex is 0x‭556677CC‬. This is most probably a problem with the data type of variable 'address'. It has to be able to hold 8 bytes. So you will have to use a data type like `unsigned long long int`.

Once you have solved that, then you need to know whether the address is stored in memory in *little endian* or *big endian* order and process it accordingly.

Update:
Just saw your edited question. 
If you expect the following conversion:
708877665544332211 into 0x1122334455667788

then even something like this will work:

```
unsigned char bMemory[] = {0x70,0x88,0x77,0x66,0x55,0x44,0x33,0x22,0x11};

int main()
{
    unsigned long long int address = *((unsigned long long int *)(&bMemory[1]));
    printf("\n Address is %llX", address );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will violate C's [strict aliasing rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) .

Comment: @MichaelPetch in one of the comments there is "the `char *` will not break it, as it can be retyped to anything"... (I have no idea what is correct, but I break the strict aliasing rule often when I need to work with the same memory content in different ways :/ ....old habits die hard and if all you see are bits...)

Comment: @Ped7g In this case you are accessing an element of the `bMemory` array (which is an array of characters) through a pointer of `unsigned long long`. This violates strict aliasing. Had you had the reverse like a pointer to `unsigned long long` the exception to the aliasing rules would have allowed you to access each byte of the `unsigned long long` through a `char *`.

Comment: In this case I'd probably consider using memcpy like this `unsigned long long address;` `memcpy (&address, bMemory+1, sizeof (address));` . If using builtins and optimization this should reduce to reasonable code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the byte order. Maybe you can try the following:

```
address = memory[8];
address |= memory[7]<<8;
address |= memory[6]<<16;
address |= memory[5]<<24;
address |= memory[4]<<32;
address |= memory[3]<<40;
address |= memory[2]<<48;
address |= memory[1]<<56;
```

P.S.: It would help if you code post the full code (including the printing).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I should have just been appending the bits and then shifting them down 8 every time.

```
for(int i = 8; i < 0; i--){
  address<<=8;
  address |= memory[i];
}
```

Comment: `0 < i` ... and that doesn't make sense... and I know what, you have to cast `memory[8]` to 64b first before `<<56`. At least gcc emits warning: *"[x86-64 gcc 6.3] warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]"* ... are you using `-Wall`?